# Create a Vec<BTreeSet<char>> from Vec<Vec<char>>

Tags: collections, functional-programming, rust

I'm trying to create a vector of set (`Vec<BTreeSet<char>>`) from `Vec<Vec<char>>`. Here's my progress so far:

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

fn main() {
    // The data
    let transaction_list = [
        vec!['A','B','C','D'],
        vec!['B','B','C'],
        vec!['A','B','B','D']
    ];

    // Successfully created a set from the Vec of Vec. It contains unique chars
    let item_set: BTreeSet<char> = transaction_list.iter().flat_map(|t| t).cloned().collect();

    // Made the same Vec of Vec. Basically just experimenting with map and collect
    let the_same_transaction_list: Vec<Vec<char>> = transaction_list.iter().map(|t| t ).cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>();

    // ERROR
    let transaction_set: Vec<BTreeSet<char>> = transaction_list
                                                .iter()
                                                .map(|t| t.iter().map(|t| t).cloned().collect() )
                                                .cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```

The error message was:

```
error: the trait `core::iter::FromIterator<char>` is not implemented for the type `&_` [E0277]
                                      .map(|t| t.iter().map(|t| t).cloned().collect() )
                                                                            ^~~~~~~~~
help: see the detailed explanation for E0277
note: a collection of type `&_` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `char`
```

I haven't found the correct way to make a `Vec<BTreeSet<char>>` out of `Vec<Vec<char>>`. Here's the playground url: http://is.gd/WVONHY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is a bit odd. Here's the solution:

```
let transaction_set: Vec<BTreeSet<_>> =
    transaction_list
    .iter()
    .map(|t| t.iter().cloned().collect())
    .collect();
```

The two main changes are:

1. `map(|x| x)` is pointless. It is a no-op.
2. I removed the outer `cloned`. The result type of the `map` call is already going to be a `BTreeSet`. There's no need to then clone it again.

The latter fixes your problem, so let's look at the definition:

```
fn cloned<'a, T>(self) -> Cloned<Self> 
    where Self: Iterator<Item=&'a T>,
          T: 'a + Clone
```

To be able to call `cloned`, the iterator `Item` has to be a **reference** to something that is cloneable. However, you are trying to iterate over `BTreeSet`s, which are not references. The compiler chooses to tell you that there's no way to `collect` your inner iterator of `char` into a `&_` (a reference to some type), which would then satisfy the requirement to call `cloned`. My guess is that the inner type has more wiggle-room than the type needed by `collect`. If we rewrite the original code a bit to have a more definitive type on the inside:

```
let transaction_set: Vec<_> =
    transaction_list
    .iter()
    .map(|t| -> BTreeSet<_> {t.iter().cloned().collect()})
    .cloned().collect();
```

We get a different set of errors:

```
error: type mismatch resolving `<[closure...] as core::ops::FnOnce<(&collections::vec::Vec<char>,)>>::Output == &_`:
 expected struct `collections::btree::set::BTreeSet`,
    found &-ptr [E0271]
         .cloned().collect();
          ^~~~~~~~

error: no method named `collect` found for type `core::iter::Cloned<core::iter::Map<core::slice::Iter<'_, collections::vec::Vec<char>>, [closure...]>>` in the current scope
         .cloned().collect();
                   ^~~~~~~~~
note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `core::iter::Cloned<core::iter::Map<core::slice::Iter<'_, collections::vec::Vec<char>>, [closure...]>> : core::iter::Iterator`
```

Which helps highlight that the problem arises from the outer use of `cloned`.

Comment: Cool! Never thought that I can call iter without map/filter/fold. Thanks for your further explanation too!